# Verify account creation from text file in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, grep, cut

I am trying to output which accounts have been successfully created from a text file and which haven't. I would also like to output the number of successfully created accounts.  I currently the get the following error: grep: 3: No such file or directory. The script and text file and saved in the same folder. I have use the following commands in my script.

```
file=users.txt
verify =grep "verify" $file |cut -f2 -d:`
cat /etc/passwd | grep $verify 

echo -e "\nYou have Currently" 
cat /etc/passwd | grep $verify |wc -l; 
echo "users added from your Text File"
```

Edit:

```
#!/bin/bash
ROOT_UID=0  #The root user has a UID of 0
if [ "$UID" -ne "$ROOT_UID" ]; then
    echo "**** You must be the root user to run this script!****"
    exit
fi
clear
echo
echo  "######################################################"
echo  "##### Batch script to automate creation of users #####"
echo -e "######################################################\n"

while true;
do
    file=notvalid
    while [ $file == "notvalid" ]
    do
    #echo "repeat $repeat"
    #echo -e "\n"
    echo -n "Please enter import filename:"
    read filename
    echo -e "\r"
    exists=0
    if  [ -e $filename ]; then
        file=valid

        while IFS=":" read  firstname lastname userid password group
        do  
            egrep -i "^$userid:" /etc/passwd &>/dev/null
            if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                exists=$((exists+1)) 
                #echo -e "${firstname} ${lastname} already exists on the system"
                #grep ${userid} /etc/passwd
                aname=$( getent passwd "$userid" | cut -d: -f3)
                echo "Account Exists: $aname" 
                euserid=$( getent passwd "$userid" | cut -d: -f1)
                echo "User ID: $userid"
                homedir=$( getent passwd "$userid" | cut -d: -f6)
                echo "Home Directory: $homedir"
                usershell=$( getent passwd "$userid" | cut -d: -f7)
                echo "User Shell: $usershell"   
                g=$( id -Gn "$userid")
                echo "Groups: $g"
                echo -e "\r" 
            else
                egrep -i "^$group:" /etc/group &>/dev/null
                if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
                    /usr/sbin/addgroup ${group} &>/dev/null
                fi
                useradd -d /home/"${userid}" -m -s /bin/bash -c \
"${firstname}${lastname}" -g "${group}" "${userid}"
                echo "Creating Account: ${firstname} ${lastname}"
                nuserid=$( getent passwd "$userid" | cut -d: -f1)
                echo "Creating User ID: ${nuserid}"
                { echo ${password}; echo ${password}; } |  sudo passwd ${userid} > /dev/null 2>&1
                echo "Creating Password: ${password}"
                echo "Creating Home Directory: /home/${userid}"
                echo "Creating User Shell: /bin/bash"
                echo -e "Assigning Group: ${group}\n"
            fi

        done < $filename
    else
        echo -e "##### CANNOT  FIND OR LOCATE FILE #####"
    fi

    verify=`grep "verify" /home/pi/$filename | cut -f3 -d:`
    echo "$verify"
    count=0
    for id in $verify
        do grep -wo ^$id /etc/passwd && count=$((count+1))
    done
    echo $count users added from your text file
    echo these are not added:
    for id in $verify
        do grep -wq ^$id /etc/passwd || echo $id
    done 
    while true
    do
    echo -n "Create additional accounts [y/n]: "
    read opt
    if [[ $opt == "n" || $opt == "y" ]];then
        break
    else
        echo "Invalid Input"
    fi
    done

    if [ $opt = "n" ]; then
        clear
        break
    else
        clear
    fi
done
```

Comment: you have spelled 'varify' incorrectly in your first cat command.

Comment: You can't have a space between variable name and command ... and to execute a system command you need to wrap it up nicely **verify=$(grep "verify" $file |cut -f2 -d:)**

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Used shellcheck which has help me tidy up the formatting etc however, it states 'Useless cat. Consider 'cmd < file......?

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there.

The main issue with your approach is that you try to search for multiple accounts at once with grep. The variable `verify` has multiple userids so you need to process it one by one.

```
file=users.txt
verify=`grep "verify" $file | cut -f2 -d:`
count=0
for id in $verify
  do grep -wo ^$id /etc/passwd && count=$((count+1))
done
echo $count users added from your text file
echo these are not added:
for id in $verify
  do grep -wq ^$id /etc/passwd || echo $id
done
```

The `for` loop will take each element in your `verify` variable into `id` and search with grep (-w matches only whole words, not fragments, ^ matches the beginning of line and -o outputs only the matching word not the whole line).
We count the number of matches in the `count` variable. Alternative approach to run the for loop twice and pipe the second one to `wc -l` as you did.
&& operator means it will increase `count` if the previous command found a match (the return code of grep was 0).

The next loop will not print matching ids (-q), and will echo `id` if grep did not found a match (the return code was not 0). This is achieved with the || operator.

One last note on iteration of a list: if the members can contain spaces (unlike userids), you should use `${verify[@]}` (this is a bash-ism) instead of `$verify` .

And forget this: `cat /etc/passwd | grep pattern`, use `grep pattern /etc/passwd` instead.

Comment: I tried the code in my script but it just seems to split and print the string verify. It doesn't seem to be treating the    `| cut -f2 -d:` as a command

Comment: It does split the string `verify` but prints only the ids found in /etc/passwd. Maybe all the ids were created successfully in users.txt so you did not notice the difference. The `for` loop will search each id in /etc/passwd and will print only the matching ids.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong. To test what is going on I printed the id in the first loop. It prints grep, "verify", $file etc. Each on a new line. It seems to splitting the string 'verify' rather than the actual file. cut -d':'  -f3 $file as an isolated command cuts the file fine.

Comment: You already have the userids to check in the `verify` variable. If you copy and paste your code here, we can take a look.